# require.context() equivalent in Browserify

Tags: javascript, webpack, browserify

In a project using Webpack, we can use `require.context()` to export a few `.js` files into one module. So in a `modules` directory, there are a few modules:

```
modules
-counter.js
-index.js
-mod2.js
somefile.js
```

The `counter.js` and the `mod2.js` are the modules. The `index.js` has the `require.context()`:

```
const files = require.context('.', false, /\.js$/)
const modules = {}

files.keys().forEach((key) => {
   if (key === './index.js') return
   modules[key.replace(/(\.\/|\.js)/g, '')] = files(key).default
})

export default modules
```

So in a separate file outside of `modules` folder, the `somefile.js`, I can do this:

```
import modules from './modules';
new Something({
  modules
});
```

**But `require.context()` is only in Webpack. Since Browserify is comparable to Webpack, is there a Browserify equivalent of doing this?**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and ended up using the require-bulk npm module and then [bulkify](https://github.com/substack/bulkify) to achieve the desired effect as Webpack's require.context. 
In your index.js file, it would be something like:

```
const bulk = require('bulk-require')
bulk(__dirname, ['./**/!(*.index).js'])
```

This would include all the files in the directory